# How to stop the value of an .each loop being the same when appending buttons to a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    var number = 0;
    $.getJSON("blogData.json", function(data) {

    $.each(data, function (index, entry) {
        console.log(index);
        $("#posts").append("<h3>" + entry.title + "</h3>");
        $("#posts").append("<h4>" + entry.desc + "</h4>");
        $("#posts").append("<h4>" + entry.author + "</h4>");
        $("#posts").append("<p>" + entry.post + "</p>");
        $("#posts").append("<br>");
        $("#posts").append('<button onclick=save(number)>Read More</button>');
        $("#posts").append("<br><br>");
        number++;
    });

});
```

I want to be able to assign a unique value to every button in order to pass this value to other functions. The context of this is a blog stored in a JSON file where the values of the posts are called via index. I wish to be able to view one post individually by clicking on the button for that specific post.

Answer (score 2):

You have used the variable as `string` type. All what you need is to concatenate the variable's value.

```
$("#posts").append('<button onclick=save(' + number + ')>Read More</button>');
```

Comment: Id like to take the time to thank you so much for this. Ive spent multiple hours on this and you have made a young student able to finally go home! Thank you!

Comment: @R31D :) Glad for you

Comment: why keep the `onclick`? Shame to mix obtrusive and unobtrusive script

Comment: I know that, I just give fast answer for the solution

Comment: @R31D that is priority, but he is right. It will be better to attach event handlers not via markup.